# Can anyone help me to check my jquery.ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/BookStore1.1/UserServlet",
        data: {method: "ajaxValidateLoginname", loginname: "value"},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        succees: function (result) {
            alert("fffff");
            if (!result) {
                $("#" + id + "Error").text("The user name has been registered!");
                showError($("#" + id + "Error"));
                return false;
            }
        }
```

this is for check the user name whether have already existed.

Comment: To begin with your 'success' spelling is wrong - succees, change that it should work

Comment: and never ever us `async: false`. it is a terrible practice and you should be seeing deprecation warnings

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked that jquery doesn't go in conflict? Try

```
jQuery.ajax.()
```

Instead of

```
$.ajax()
```

Also, try with lowercase

```
{
   method: 'post'
}

Or

{
   type: 'post'
}
```

Check what you receive from the response too, with

```
console.log(result)
```

Again, use with attention the type juggling, because if you use this syntax in json mode

```
if (!result) {
```

Keep in mind that result may be always an object, also empty

Comment: case is not relevant for method/type .. it is normalized internally. As for `$ != jQuery` there would be errors thrown. There are a variety of other issues that are far more common than this